# How do you read a CSV file and display the results in a grid in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, csv

How do you read a CSV file and display the results in a grid in Visual Basic 2010? This sounds so simple but I still can't find the answer to it after googling for a while. I have DataGridView on a form and it's called DataGridView1. I have a CSV with just 3 columns of data and I want to be able to display them.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-csv-files-in-net

Answer (score 18):

Use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class built into the .Net framework.

Here's some code copied from an [MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/cc7d1f3f-ef0e-4b37-92f6-d4990269a166) by Paul Clement. It converts the CSV into a new in-memory DataTable and then binds the DataGridView to the DataTable

```
    Dim TextFileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Documents and Settings\...\My Documents\My Database\Text\SemiColonDelimited.txt")

    TextFileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    TextFileReader.SetDelimiters(";")

    Dim TextFileTable As DataTable = Nothing

    Dim Column As DataColumn
    Dim Row As DataRow
    Dim UpperBound As Int32
    Dim ColumnCount As Int32
    Dim CurrentRow As String()

    While Not TextFileReader.EndOfData
        Try
            CurrentRow = TextFileReader.ReadFields()
            If Not CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
                ''# Check if DataTable has been created
                If TextFileTable Is Nothing Then
                    TextFileTable = New DataTable("TextFileTable")
                    ''# Get number of columns
                    UpperBound = CurrentRow.GetUpperBound(0)
                    ''# Create new DataTable
                    For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound
                        Column = New DataColumn()
                        Column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
                        Column.ColumnName = "Column" & ColumnCount
                        Column.Caption = "Column" & ColumnCount
                        Column.ReadOnly = True
                        Column.Unique = False
                        TextFileTable.Columns.Add(Column)
                    Next
                End If
                Row = TextFileTable.NewRow
                For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound
                    Row("Column" & ColumnCount) = CurrentRow(ColumnCount).ToString
                Next
                TextFileTable.Rows.Add(Row)
            End If
        Catch ex As _
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & _
            "is not valid and will be skipped.")
        End Try
    End While
    TextFileReader.Dispose()
    frmMain.DataGrid1.DataSource = TextFileTable
```

Comment: `TextFileReader.SetDelimeters(new string() {";"})` May this will help anyone as it helped me

Answer (score 4):

Consider this snippet of code. Modify as you see fit, or to fit your requirements. You'll need to have `Imports` statements for `System.IO` and `System.Data.OleDb`.

```
Dim fi As New FileInfo("c:\foo.csv")
Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Text;Data Source=" & fi.DirectoryName

Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
conn.Open()

'the SELECT statement is important here, 
'and requires some formatting to pull dates and deal with headers with spaces.
Dim cmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Foo, Bar, FORMAT(""SomeDate"",'YYYY/MM/DD') AS SomeDate, ""SOME MULTI WORD COL"", FROM " & fi.Name, conn)

Dim adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
adapter1.SelectCommand = cmdSelect

Dim ds As New DataSet
adapter1.Fill(ds, "DATA")

myDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView 
myDataGridView.DataBind
conn.Close()
```

Comment: You're using a database engine to parse a CSV file?  That seems like super-duper overkill.  At least the code is short :)

Comment: @Meryln: thanks, I think. Not sure what could be considered overkill about querying via OleDb/Jet. Overkill would be Excel COM APIs, in my estimation. The OP didn't have any requirements about performance, elegance, coolness, or enterprise patterns. It's only one suggestion. Looking forward to your solution.

Comment: @Merlyn, @p.campbell OleDB/Jet can be considered overkill, because Microsoft have built a [class for reading CSV files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) into the .Net framework.

Comment: you rock! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Consider this CodeProject article/project: [LINQ TO CSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx.).

It will enable you to create a custom class that is shaped like your .csv file's columns. You'd then consume the CSV and bind to your DataGridView.

```
Dim cc As new CsvContext()
Dim inputFileDescription As New CsvFileDescription() With { _
    .SeparatorChar = ","C, _
    .FirstLineHasColumnNames = True _
}

Dim products As IEnumerable(Of Product) = _
     cc.Read(Of Product)("products.csv", inputFileDescription)

' query from CSV, load into a new class of your own   
Dim productsByName = From p In products
    Select New CustomDisplayClass With _
       {.Name = p.Name, .SomeDate = p.SomeDate, .Price = p.Price}, _        
    Order By p.Name


myDataGridView1.DataSource = products
myDataGridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\abc.csv")
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little more elegant

```
'populate DT from .csv file

 Dim items = (From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:YourData.csv") _
 Select Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(","c), Function(v) _ 
 v.ToString.TrimStart(""" ".ToCharArray).TrimEnd(""" ".ToCharArray))).ToArray

Dim Your_DT As New DataTable
For x As Integer = 0 To items(0).GetUpperBound(0)
Your_DT.Columns.Add()
Next

For Each a In items
Dim dr As DataRow = Your_DT.NewRow
dr.ItemArray = a
Your_DT.Rows.Add(dr)
Next

Your_DataGrid.DataSource = Your_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can read data from `.csv` file using `OLEDB` provider.

```
  If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim sConnectionStringz As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Text;Data Source=" & fi.DirectoryName
            Dim objConn As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionStringz)
            objConn.Open()
            'DataGridView1.TabIndex = 1
            Dim objCmdSelect As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " & fi.Name, objConn)
            Dim objAdapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter
            objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect
            Dim objDataset1 As New DataSet
            objAdapter1.Fill(objDataset1)

            '--objAdapter1.Update(objDataset1) '--updating
            DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataset1.Tables(0).DefaultView
        Catch ex as Exception
           MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            objConn.Close()
        End Try
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
Dim dataTable1 As New DataTable
                dataTable1.Columns.Add("FECHA")
                dataTable1.Columns.Add("TT")
                dataTable1.Columns.Add("DESCRIPCION")
                dataTable1.Columns.Add("No. DOC")
                dataTable1.Columns.Add("DEBE")
                dataTable1.Columns.Add("HABER")
                dataTable1.Columns.Add("SALDO")

For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(objetos.url)
                    dataTable1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
                Next
```

Comment: can you use a Datatable :)