# CSV to DataGrid in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I don't know how to load my CSV file load into a datagrid view in vb2005.

I have two records as the following

```
9,N,010324405,,,,,,,,05071958,UU,Yoeun,,,,,,,,,,,M,M,KHM,,P,RESID,,,,,"St. Lum,Phum Ti Pir,Chrouy Changva,Ruessei Kaev",,,,PP,,KHM,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,215,S,,DDD_70300098149,21082012,PLN,KHR,6000,1206013,N,N,6000,M,,12042013,67000.00,NO,120000,0,12052013,0,30042013,,,,

10,N,00032529,,,,,,,,18021962,SDM,Sok,,,,,,,,,,,M,M,KHM,,P,RESID,,,,,"#281,Phum Ti Muoy,Chrouy Changva,Ruessei Kaev",,,,PP,,KHM,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,215,S,,DDD_703004167,20022013,PLN,KHR,10000,1510013,N,N,12000,M,,1802013,15660.00,NO,75000,0,1505213,0,3002013,,,,
```

My code:

```
For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathname)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
Next
```

I want to read this format load to datagridview, any solution?

Comment: Don't use split, it will generate wrong result.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code

```
Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(pathname)

TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {","}

While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
    Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()

    If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
        Next
    End If

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row1)
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the example with CSV library:

[at Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485883/how-do-you-read-a-csv-file-and-display-the-results-in-a-grid-in-visual-basic-201), using `OLEDBCommand` you can read *CSV* format. Take a look at `p.campbell`'s solution.

Comment: can give me example coding.

Comment: Have you checked the link and tried p.campbell's answer ? Its an example code.