# C#: Checking That ArrayList Elements have specific type

Tags: c#, csv, arraylist, validation

```
               ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList();


      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
          if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Puts elements in table
                fileList.Add(line.Split(';'));
            }

            file.Close();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < (fileList[i] as string[]).Length; x++)
            {
               // if (x ==0)
              //  { 
                    //fileList[0] must Be int 
              //  }
               // if (x==1)
                    //fileList[1] must be string 

                this.textBox2.Text += ((fileList[i] as string[])[x] + " ");
            }

            this.textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

I am so far here.

I take the elements from a CSV file.

I need now to be sure that the 1 **column** has only numbers-integers (1,2,3,4,5), the second **column** has only names(so it will have the type string or character), the third surnames etc. etc.

The rows are presented like this : 1;George;Mano;

How can I be sure that the CSV file has the correct types?

I think that any more code about this problem will be placed inside the 2 for statements.

Thank you very much,

George.

Comment: Your post indicates that your rows are like `1;2;3;`, `johnson;smith;gower`, `john;james;susan`.  Is that correct, or are they like this: `1;johnson;john`, `2;smith;james`, `3;gower;susan`

Comment: you didn't ask this, so I'll just leave a comment. Why reinvent the wheel? There are several open source csv libraries. I use linq2csv, which you can use with DataAnnotation attributes for validation. See this for links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-csv-files-in-net

Comment: @Agent-j - I do believe his original question said that the first column ( the first value ) would be an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Now that we know it's really CSV, here's a columnar answer  ;-)**

Your `ArrayList` contains `string[]`, so you need to verify that each array has the appropriate type of string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
{
   string[] lineItems = (string[])fileList[i];
   if (!Regex.IsMatch (lineItems[0], "^\d+$")) // numbers
      throw new ArgumentException ("invalid id at row " + i);
   if (!Regex.IsMatch (lineItems[1], "^[a-zA-Z]+$")) // surnames - letters-only
      throw new ArgumentException ("invalid surname at row " + i);
   if (!Regex.IsMatch (lineItems[2], "^[a-zA-Z]+$")) // names - letters-only
      throw new ArgumentException ("invalid name at row " + i);
}
```

Comment: @Ramhound, that is not true.  If this was generic, it would be `List<string[]>`.  Notice how the OP does an `fileList.Add (string.split...)`, not an `fileList.AddRange(string.split(...))`

Comment: I never said it was a generic collection.  Although looking at the code again I noticed I missed the Split statement which returns a String[].

Comment: @Ramhound, I only meant to describe the contents of the ArrayList, I did not mean to imply you missed that genericness of the type.   :-) I appologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I understand.  I appreciate the clarification as I had missed the String.Split in my intial response.

Comment: what does the line `string[] lineItems = (string[])fileList[i];` do ? I have already difined a my ArrayList  `ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList();`

Comment: I used this piece of code to solve the problem but I replaced the `throw new ArgumentException` lines with printing in text box method. Thank you very much

Comment: @george, It pulls an a string array out of the arraylist at index i.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question needs more work.

You don't show your declaration for `filelist`. Whatever it is, there is no reason to convert it to `string[]` just to get the length. The length with be the same no matter what type it is. You cannot use this method to determine which items are strings.

You'll need to loop through the items and see if they contain only digits or whatever.

Also, your code to read CSV files is not quote right. CSV files are comma-separated. And it's possible that they could contain commas within double quotes. These commas should be ignored. A better way to read CSV files can be seen [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c).

Comment: look at the edit made on the code. My CSV file is separated with ;

Comment: @george: If it's separated with `;`, then it isn't CSV.

Comment: @Jonathan - Its still a seperated value one could argue that any symbol that does not appear in the data ( unless its within quotes )could be the character which seperates the value.

Comment: @Ramhound: CSV stands for *Comma-Separated Values*.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood - I don't disagree for what it actually stands. To say his file is not a CSV when you can have Excel load a CSV and have it nearly use any character as the seperator is when I don't understand the reason you even bring it up. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values ( German and Dutch use the ; as the seperator ).

Comment: @Ramhound: It's not my opinion--that's what it stands for. And it's very interesting that you disagree without telling me what *you* think the 'C' stands for. Either way, this is no longer productive. You are free to think the 'C' stands for whatever you want it to.

Comment: @Jonathan - I actually agree for what it stands for.  Does not change the fact the character used to seperate the values can be another value.  In general a CSV is a simple way to present a table.

Answer (score 1):

An **Arraylist** contains object.

**System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine** returns a **String**.

Checking the value of the first line read and trying to convert the string into an integer would be a valid approach.

Your current approach is adding the String that is returned by **System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine** into your collection which you later turn into a String[] by using the String.Split method.

Your other requirements will be a greal more difficult because every line you are reading is a String already.  So you would have to look at each character within the string to determine if it appears to be a name.

In other words you might want to find a different way to provide an input.  I would agree that a regular expression might be the best way to get rid of junk data.

Comment: WHat do you mean exactly regular expression?

Comment: @George Mano - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class.

Comment: -1: Unhelpful and information lite answer. e.g. How would the user use a regex in this instance?

Comment: @Binary - The question itself is not exactly the best either.

Comment: A poor quality question is no excuse for a poor quality answer. You've so many other options, just some are to clarify the question, downvote the question or leave the question alone. Stack Overflow was specifically created to [Make the Internet a better place](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/04/19.html), every answer here should conform to this ideal, it is one of the reasons sarcasm and let-me-google-that-for-you answers are quickly put down. This answer effectively does nothing to help the asker.

Comment: @Binary Worrier - We will have to agree that we have different ways of thinking.  I would argue telling the author to use a regular expression is a valid statement.  I would agree that treetey's answer contained no clarification.

Comment: @Ramhound: Obviously yes, we do all think differently, however this particular way of thinking is not in line with best practises on Stack Exchange sites in general, and on Stack Overflow in particular.

Answer (score 0):

fileList[0] must Be int:

`int x;`

`if(int.TryParse(fileList[0], out x)){ //do whatever here and x will have that integer value. TryParse will return false if it's not an integer so the if will not fire}`

fileList[1] must be string :

iterate over the string and check each element is a letter. look at the `char.` methods for the appropriate one.