# How to read rows with specific value from csv file

Tags: c#

I have a sorted csv file. How to read just rows with ordered value and write them to datagridview.For example read just rows where value of Age is 22. the file looks like:

```
ID Name Surname Age Salary
1  John Asben   33  1000
2  Adam Smith   22  1200
3  Amanda J     22  2000
4  George Villis 36  2300
```

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, we will NOT write your code for you.  So, that leads me to ask, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: And how will you deal with "Billy Joe Smith" ?

Comment: Why not read the whole file, map it to a class and do the filtering there?

Comment: I have tryedDataRow[] foundRows;
foundRows = dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Select("Age Like 'A%'");

Answer (score 1):

About reading CSV files in .NET: [Reading a CSV file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-csv-files-in-net)

Depending on the CSV parser type and the classes you'll get the CSV data in, you could apply a filter while parsing, apply a filter on the parsed data or add a [View filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#filtering) to the grid. I'm sure there are also other methods.