# string parsing challenge in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, csv

I have written a desktop app to help some coworkers process some huge .csv files they have. Each "column" within a line (row) is in quotation marks, so it looks something like this:

"something", "blah-blah", "another thing", "etc and so forth"

My simple little program reads a line, uses String.Split(',') function to get an array of values, and off I go to do my processing...UNTIL I hit a row like this:

"something", "blah-blah", "Values, 1, 2, 3", "etc and so forth"

The commas within the quoted value make the Split function behave in an unintended way.

Is there an "easy" (built-in) way I can handle inputting the lines that will correctly parse the example above? I want to avoid having to write my own logic to trudge through each line.

I suspect that using Regular Expressions may be the key to happiness.

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can provide.

Comment: You'll find yourself repeatedly chasing down problems like this if you try to parse CSV files using String.Split, regex, or other hand-rolled simple solutions. There are several free libraries out there that do CSV file handling very well. You're way better off using one of them.

Comment: Asked an answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171480/regex-grabbing-values-between-quotation-marks

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel!  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: "I suspect that using Regular Expressions may be the key to happiness."  I suspect that you have just answered your own question :)

Comment: @Brian: I suspect not, there are better ways.

Comment: "I suspect that using Regular Expressions may be the key to happiness."  Now you have two problems.

Comment: Have look a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-csv-files-in-net unless you are mad keen on re-inventing wheels

Comment: Not an expert on regular expressions, but don't think this can be achieved using them. RE are stateless

Comment: @Tigran yeah it's not a good case for RegEx, any language which uses balanced (one closing for every opening) markers of any sort to denote scope (braces, parens, quotes, ect) is not regular.

Comment: If you're parsing CSV files, you should use `TextFieldParser`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much, everyone. This is eye-opening. I think I got the little project to work sufficiently well for the task at hand. I used a simple regular expression. But, going forward, the libraries posted here seem like a much more robust way to go. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of edge cases when dealing with quoted strings in CSV and commas/quotes within them. I'd recommend using a library like [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) (or one of the others available in NuGet) that have already figured out the logic and tested it.

Other options:

- [KBCsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/)
- [CSVTools](https://github.com/MikeStall/DataTable)
- [Toolkit.Csv](http://toolkitcsv.codeplex.com/)
- [LibCSV4Net](https://github.com/dkucinskas/LibCSV4Net)

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the first and last quotation off, then it'd look like ->

```
something", "blah-blah", "Values, 1, 2, 3", "etc and so forth
```

then you can split on ", " like

```
 String.Split(@""", """);
```

or do the split first, then .Replace(@"""", "");