# displaying string of array in datagridview c# windows application

Tags: c#, list, csv

hi every one and thanks in advance i have the following code for displaying records from .csv file to datagridview(has three column Number,Date,Message) in c# Windows Application.

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\messages.csv").Select(a => a.Split(',')).ToList();
 foreach (string[] s in lines)
 {
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s[2], s[5], s[7]);
 }
```

its work fine for the first 7 occurrence of ',' but i have others lines in .csv file that have more then 7 ',' so i want that al the occurance of ',' after 7 should combine with the 7 th one for my third column in datagridview name as Message

example of one line in .csv file

sms,deliver,"+919999999999","","","2013.08.01 09:40","","Following apartment in mumbai for lease: SHIKHA, Near SHATRANJ, Off Carter Road, Khar Garden facing 1500 sq.ft. 2 hours notice for inspection. --Rohit J."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [overload of Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) which allows you to choose the number of elements to return (`7` in this case).

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\messages.csv")
                             .Select(a => a.Split(new[] {','}, 7)).ToList();

foreach (string[] s in lines)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s[2], s[5], s[6]);
}
```

Comment: @ShaikhMohammadSufiyan - Change `s[7]` to `s[6]`. Alternatively, if that's getting one result down, change `7` to `8` (so that 8 results are returned and keep your `s[7]` call).

Comment: Thank you sir ... i get the result i m looking for..but one more thing sir..i also  wanted to remove the double quotes from the result..how can i do that sir...

Comment: @keyboardP you got me there by secs, up voting yours

Comment: @ShaikhMohammadSufiyan - Do you mean all double quotes, or just the empty ones?

Comment: you can use [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) to remove the quotes

Comment: the empty one and also the starting and ending of all the column

Comment: Thank you @keyboardP sir for all the rest..thank you very much...again..and bansi sir for the trim

Comment: @bansi - +1 to you too for getting there at the same time and the Trim suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\messages.csv").Select(a => a.Split(',',7)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading/parsing a CSV by simply splitting on commas is a bad idea. Consider the following table:

```
Col 1             Col 2              Col 3
Hello             How are you        I am fine
Hello, world      Are you well       Yes I am
```

The CSV would look something like:

```
Col 1, Col 2, Col 3
Hello, How are you, I am fine
"Hello, world", Are you well, Yes I am
```

Splitting by commas will munge the second line. Nested quotes and newlines make the job even harder.

Instead, don't bother reinventing the wheel, and use a parser. Look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-csv-files-in-net) for some suggestions.