# Processing csv files in c# with double quotes

Tags: c#, csv

I have a csv file whose values needs to be dumped to SQL server as table. All the Columns are coming in as `strings`. When I  `SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy`....Records gets inserted with double quotes. I do not understand why? 
the csv file when opened in excel has no quotes. I cannot use a `Replace` function to remove because many fields have double quotes within them.
Any suggestions please..

Thanks
MR

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading CSV files in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-csv-files-in-net)

Comment: please post the code you are using to stream the csv file

Comment: The above link does not have the answer.

Comment: Here's what I do 1) Using ReadLines,WriteAllLines I write the .csv file to .txt file.2) add tabs after every column 3) Using stream reader I open the text file and add column header and columns to Datatable. 4) I use SQLBULKCOPY with column mappings and write to server.

Comment: If you bulk insert the CSV file using BULK INSERT in TSQL (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx; no need to re-write the CSV file), does it also come through with quotes?