# Error inserting data from many method return lists to a database in c#

Tags: winforms, arraylist, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I need help here with part of my code so here it is:

I have 6 methods as you can see below that parse incoming data and then returns it as a list, so my issue is to send that list data to my database table SerialNumber, each method of the lists is a separate field that will fill a database column.

So for example the parse material will fill the database materiallookupcode column and the same for the others.

Here is an image of the database table
[image]

Here is the code of all 5 methods that reads the data and then returns it and I need this data send to my database

```
private List<string> ParseMaterial()
        {
            var materialList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var material in _connection.GetBarcodeList())
            {
                materialList.Add(material.Substring(10, 5));
            }

            return materialList;
        }

        private List<string> ParseLot()
        {
            var lotList = new List<string>();
            var establishmentList = GetEstablishmentCode();

            foreach (var lot in _connection.GetBarcodeList())
            {
                if (establishmentList.Contains("038"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.LoganSport038Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("072"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.LouisaCounty072Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("086"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Madison086Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("089"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Perry089Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("069"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.StormLake069Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("088"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Waterloo088Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("265"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.GoodLetsVille265Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("087"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.CouncilBluffs087Property);
                }
                if (establishmentList.Contains("064"))
                {
                    lotList.Add(lot.Substring(28, 6) + _lotEstablishment.Sherman064Property);
                }

            }

            return lotList;
        }

        private List<string> ParseSerialNumber()
        {
            var serialNumberList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var serialNumber in _connection.GetBarcodeList())
            {
                serialNumberList.Add(serialNumber.Substring(36, 10));
            }

            return serialNumberList;
        }

        public List<string> ParseNetWeight()
        {
            var netWeightList = new List<string>();


            foreach (var netWeight in _connection.GetBarcodeList())
            {            
                netWeightList.Add(netWeight.Substring(22, 4));
            }

            return netWeightList;
        }

        public List<string> ParseGrossWeight()
        {
            var grossWeightList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var grossWeight in _connection.GetBarcodeList())
            {
                grossWeightList.Add(grossWeight.Substring(22, 4));
            }

            return grossWeightList;
        }

        public List<string> FullBarcode()
        {
            var receiveFullBarcodeList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var fullBarcode in _connection.GetBarcodeList())
            {
                receiveFullBarcodeList.Add(fullBarcode);
            }

            return receiveFullBarcodeList;
        }

        public List<string> GetEstablishmentCode()
        {
            var establishmentList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var establishmentCode in _connection.GetBarcodeList())
            {
                establishmentList.Add(establishmentCode.Substring(36, 3));
            }

            return establishmentList;
        }
```

The issue is here the button when clicking will read all 5 methods and send it to the database, I am sure the part where I making the list of variables to a string and the separator part is wrong so I need how is the correct way to add those list to each column of the database

```
    private async void btn_SubmitData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
                 // parse list methodss
            var materialList = ParseMaterial();
            var lotList = ParseLot();
            var netWeightList = ParseNetWeight();
            var grossWeightList = ParseGrossWeight();
            var serialNumberList = ParseSerialNumber();
            var fullSerialNumberList = FullBarcode();

            var material = "";
            var lot = "";
            var net = "";
            var gross = "";
            var serial = "";
            var fullSerial = "";

            var currentUser = _currentUser.GetCurrentUsernameOnApp();
            var licensePlateId = GetLicensePlateIds();

            for (var i = 0; i < _connection.GetBarcodeList().Count; i++)
            {
                 material = materialList[i];
                 lot = lotList[i];
                 net = netWeightList[i];
                 gross = grossWeightList[i];
                 serial = serialNumberList[i];
                 fullSerial = fullSerialNumberList[i];
            }

            // database table and columns
            var serialNumbersInsert = new List<SerialNumber>
            {
                new SerialNumber
                {
                    SerialNumberLookupCode = serial,
                    NetWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(net) / 100,
                    GrossWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(gross) / 100,
                    LotLookupCode = lot,
                    MaterialLookupCode = material,
                    FullSerialNumberLookupCode = fullSerial,
                    CreatedSysDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    ModifiedSysDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    CreatedSysUser = currentUser,
                    ModifiedSysUser = currentUser,
                    LicensePlateId = licensePlateId
                }
            };

            // insert to the database
            foreach (var list in serialNumbersInsert)
            {
                _unitOfWork.SerialNumbers.Add(list);
            }
            await _unitOfWork.Complete();
}
```

Here is the SerialNumber domain class that represents a database table using a code first migration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BarcodeReceivingApp.Core.Domain
{
    // domain class, represents a database table in sql server using code 
    // first migration
    public class SerialNumber
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int LicensePlateId { get; set; }
        public string FullSerialNumberLookupCode { get; set; }
        public string SerialNumberLookupCode { get; set; }
        public decimal NetWeight { get; set; }
        public decimal GrossWeight { get; set; }
        public string LotLookupCode { get; set; }
        public string MaterialLookupCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedSysDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedSysDateTime { get; set; }
        public string CreatedSysUser { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedSysUser { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I search other places but could not find a good solution so far, so any help is appreciate it.

Comment: anyone can see my issue and get some solution if possible?

Comment: can someone let me know a solution on my issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You have these lists of strings and a SerialNumber class that you have not shown where you are assigning lists to the properties. I expect you are trying to somehow combine the lists or use them as lookups? I can't tell.

Comment: Hello @SteveGreene, Thanks for the feedback. Shortly I will add the SerialNumber class that class is a domain class which represents the creation of a database table using code first migration, so I am trying to send the data of those lists to that database table, but shortly I will add that class and modified my body description to make more sense so you can help me on  my issue

Comment: Hello @SteveGreene I updated my body description and added the SerialNumber domain class and an image of the database table

Comment: OK, so for example, this line `SerialNumberLookupCode = serialNumberList` would make no sense since you are assigning a collection to a single variable. Do all the lists correspond to different fields? If that is the case you could loop through and do the assignment `SerialNumberLookupCode = serialNumberList[i]`

Comment: I see, yes I was thinking the same thing before your message, I am going to update my code so you can review it and see if all looks good.

Comment: Hello @SteveGreene, I updated the code the btn_SubmitData_Click button body logic please review I ran a for loop and assign each list to a new varible like for example serial = serialNumberList[i] and the same for the other ones and then use those new variables inside the insert serialnumber part of the code since each list corresponds to a single field in the database table

Comment: And does it work?

Comment: Yes I was able to insert the data to my table I just sent 10 records each field. but please let me know that your solution I put is what you were thinking?

Comment: There are may ways. Ideally, if all those fields are in a single table you would parse it to single record instead of several lists, do your validation and cleanup, and then insert the whole record at once.

Comment: I see, make sense that is something I wanted to do at first to parse all into one field and then insert it to the table but I couldn't, can you put an example code of your solution please? just an small code test that way gives me an idea and I could do the rest.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096284/i-want-to-import-data-from-csv-file-to-sql-database-using-entity-framework), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994996/save-rows-to-database-from-uploaded-web-api-csv-and-entity-framework) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/242602/Strongly-typed-Csv-reader-CsvToObj-and-Code-First) are a few for starters.

Comment: thanks, man. I will review them. how can I mark this as the solution?

Comment: If you come to a solution you should post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189229/discussion-between-newcoder-and-steve-greene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my question, what I did is to assign all lists in a loop and then assign them to each column in the database.

But I am still searching for a better and more clean way to this solution

```
private async void btn_SubmitData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // parse list methods - represents each field of the database column
        var materialList = ParseMaterial();
        var lotList = ParseLot();
        var netWeightList = ParseNetWeight();
        var grossWeightList = ParseGrossWeight();
        var serialNumberList = ParseSerialNumber();
        var fullSerialNumberList = FullBarcode();
        var currentUser = _currentUser.GetCurrentUsernameOnApp();
        var licensePlateId = GetLicensePlateIds();


        for (var i = 0; i < _connection.GetBarcodeList().Count; i++)
        {
             var serialNumbersInsert = new List<SerialNumber>
             {
                 new SerialNumber
                 {
                     SerialNumberLookupCode = materialList[i],
                     NetWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(netWeightList[i]) / 100,
                     GrossWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(grossWeightList[i]) / 100,
                     LotLookupCode = lotList[i],
                     MaterialLookupCode = materialList[i],
                     FullSerialNumberLookupCode = fullSerialNumberList[i],
                     CreatedSysDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                     ModifiedSysDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                     CreatedSysUser = currentUser,
                     ModifiedSysUser = currentUser,
                     LicensePlateId = licensePlateId
                 }
             };

             foreach (var list in serialNumbersInsert)
             {
                 _unitOfWork.SerialNumbers.Add(list);
             }
             await _unitOfWork.Complete();
        }

    }
```