# Loading CSV data using SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord with enclosing and nulls

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, jdbc, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to load CSV data using the SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord, however it seems that this doesn't allow for enclosed fields (stripping quotes) and supply a value for NULL.

Any suggestions on how to get this working? Seems like such basic functionality needed for loading a CSV file.

Code i'm currently using:

```
final SQLServerBulkCopy copymanager = new SQLServerBulkCopy(connection);
final SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord csv = new SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord(datafile.toString(), true);

final ResultSet resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(
        String.format("select * from [%s].[%s]", getSchema(), tableName));
for (int i = 1; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
    csv.addColumnMetadata(i, resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnType(i),
            resultSet.getMetaData().getPrecision(i), resultSet.getMetaData().getScale(i));
}

copymanager.setDestinationTableName(tableName);
copymanager.writeToServer(csv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, the source for SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord has a [comment](https://www.javatips.net/api/mssql-jdbc-master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord.java)

> - Both BCP and BULK INSERT considers double quotes as part of the data and throws error if any data (say "10") is to be
> - inserted into an numeric column. Our implementation does the same.

that means you will have to parse each row in your code to unquote quoted values.

As far as supplying a value for NULL, you can do it in your code our supply a DEFAULT value in the table.  Your choice.

Comment: Well thanks, but still ugly... for ex. Postgresql driver has an option to define the enclosing character, even optionally and can define a string value for null.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-a-csv-file-in-net mentions using a .NET class to parse csv,  it might help you here

Comment: I ended up using the SqlBulkCopy class with an InputStream and rewriting the original file without qoutes and unused seperator.

Comment: Maybe I now ended up extending the SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord and build the backend based on FastCSV... Seems more seamless; Can share part of the code if anyone is interested.